# How to fix exceptions with Converter after spring boot version upgrade

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

I recently upgraded from spring boot version 1.5.7 to 2.1.4. After upgrading, I am getting exceptions with Converters where the @Query annotation is used with spring data. 
Exception stack trace below.

Can you please suggest if any dependency versions should be changed to fix this? Or a customer converter needs to be written?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.HashMap<?, ?>] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.example.Stage.XXXX]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.CollectionToCollectionConverter.convert(CollectionToCollectionConverter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41)
    ... 150 more
```

Code posted:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface FileStagedEventRepository extends JpaRepository<FileStagedEvent, Long> {

@Query(value = "select new map(id as id, fileName as fileName, recType as recType) FROM FileStagedEvent where id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
    public Map<String, String> findById(@Param("id") Long id);  
}
```

The `select new map` section seems to be the issue. I am not sure how this map function works.

Comment: I think you first must upgrade from 1.5.7 to 2.0.0 after your 2.1.4, you can take a look the following link https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide

Comment: Try maven clean install. If it doesn't work please compare your pom.xml file completely with new generated version 2.1.4. Compare every tags.

Comment: show `@Query`-annotated method from your Repository

Comment: @JonathanJohx I tried with 2.0.9. Still same issue. I don't quite follow the github steps. I will try with 2.0.0 now.

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko: The query string is  - select new map(id as fseId, fileName as fileName, rec as rec) FROM StagedModel where id = :fseId

Comment: @DTnapaT Can you post your repository class?

Comment: @DTnapaT please add code related to this issue.

Comment: forgot to reply here. I have edited and already added code and added repository classes.